# Qlikview: Automatically select default value in listbox when selecting value in other listbox

Tags: listbox, qlikview

My question is kind of a complicated one to explain.

I have two listboxes; ShopId and PosId. a ShopId is unique, but a PosId isn't. Example population:

```
ShopId      |  PosId
1           |    1
1           |    2
2           |    1
3           |    1
```

There always has to be one and only one value selected in both listboxes ( PosId and ShopId).
My problem now is that when i select ShopId=1 and PosId=2, i can't click on ShopId=3 because ShopId3 doesn't have a PosId2.

I basically want to change my PosId to the lowest possible value when i select another shop (So that there will always be a selected value in both lisboxes).

If something is still unclear, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PosId list box with below config:
New List Box / Field / < Expression >

In expression box, enter as:

```
=MIN(PosId)
```

Then when you select the ShopId, value in this box will always show the minimum possible.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is using a trigger on the sheet.

**Event** will be change in selection on the field (in your example ShopId).

**Action** will be default selection on a field (in your example PosId)

**Note:**

- You will have to set the value of selection in Action Field such that it is universally present in all relational instances of ShopId.
- Alternatively, you can make the selection value a calculated one using set analysis.

Hope this helps.